# Confirm that an image exists on Amazon S3 server -- CURL or fsockopen

Tags: php, curl, amazon-s3, file-get-contents, fsockopen

I have some code that already checks for the existence of an image file on a remote server. This should be trivial using CURL or Fsockopen, but I have an issue.

For example, consider this URL: 
http://media-cache-ec3.pinterest.com/upload/202450945720262211_0utXb0QZ_f.jpg

The HTTP Headers on this are as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Date: Mon, 17 Sep 2012 08:10:59 GMT
ETag: "31d93cdf91def38bcdbd70786805ba2a"
Expires: Tue, 17 Sep 2013 08:10:59 GMT
Last-Modified: Mon, 17 Sep 2012 05:27:21 GMT
Server: ECS (dfw/56F1)
x-amz-id-2: Lr9D66o3dW5NN15dXhh04MSKIrwqugtFH51g8XoloI+7tItd2ITxJp3KDhVpKWm5
x-amz-request-id: 4F9888DFA41E82C6
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 168738
```

Yet, the actual page returns this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>3AB3633B5D289688</RequestId>
<HostId>
/FOF1nsbJ6slumpg2YHnhV5L+j12z3U/fp5coyi/BGG8JRT3nAtPrCHcIV3p3B0Z
</HostId>
</Error>
```

I thought just getting the URL's contents would be enough, but whether I use CURL or fsockopen or file_get_contents(), the actual content is some binary garbage. Yet, pointing the browser to that URL shows me some XML from Amazon's S3, which is what I suppose Pinterest uses.

So, question: any tips on how I could check from within the body of the response (which prints as binary junk right now) to see if there is the "AccessDenied" message there?

Here is the code I am using: 
http://chopapp.com/#1hcycm6x

Thanks!

Comment: I am not getting any XML files when using your link. Instead, I get the picture (which is the *binary garbage* i think).

Comment: Weird. This is what I see: http://imgur.com/j4ena - on Mac OSX Mountain Lion. The same thing in Chrome, Safari, Firefox.

Comment: Maybe your IP is banned or something like that? [This](http://imgur.com/oBuVf) is what I see, and so does your script I think.